# magento printed 404 page after install magento ver1.9

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

In my case, my project was implemeted in window server with magento 1.8.

and these days I got a linux server,  I installed magento 1.9.

and I moved to local extention(same code with implemented in window server).

finally I found specific page is prineted "404 not found".

For catching error, I tried to many things like cache disable.

But It is ineffective.

So I ask how I can catch 404 error.

thank you.

Comment: More than likely it's case sensitivity of your file paths that you used.  Windows ignores these typically,  where linux does not

Comment: I fixed this error. The problem is a sensitive linux. My *.php file's name has many upper case alphabet, so linux can't find path.